# Multipled conditions for showing and hidding buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conditional-statements

Im Trying to make a "update and delete button that will only show up if the user created the post or if the user or moderator AND/OR moderator .

my current posthelper is

```
  def user_is_authorized_for_post?(post)
    current_user && (current_user == post.user || current_user.admin?) 
  end
```

and my button is:

```
<% if user_is_authorized_for_post?(@post) %>
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_topic_post_path(@post.topic, @post), class: 'btn btn-success' %>
<%= link_to "Delete Post", [@post.topic, @post], method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this post?' } %>
<% end %>
```

UPDATE: i updated the PostsHelper to :

```
  def user_is_authorized_for_post?(post)
    current_user && (current_user == post.user || current_user.admin?)  || (current_user == post.user || current_user.moderator?)
  end
```

It works but my question is, is there a better way of coding this because I feel like its to long.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a shorter way to write it.

You can use guard clause to shorten the method definition:

```
def user_is_authorized_for_post?(post)
  return false unless current_user # the aforementioned guard clause
  current_user == post.user || current_user.admin? || current_user.moderator?
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is okay but a better way is to implement it using an authorization system, [**pundit**](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) is a good choice, because here the user can update the post manually via **Curl** or **Postman**

You will have **policy** classes that manages your different authorization logics:

#### The policy

```
class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def edit?
    update?
  end

  #user is equivalent to the current_user and record == post
  def update?
    user && (user == record.user || user.admin?)  || (user == record.user || user.moderator?)

  end
end
```

#### Authorize in the view

```
<% if policy(@post).edit? %>
  # the button
<% end %>
```

#### Authorize in the controller

```
def edit
  @post = Post.find params[:id]
  authorized @post
end

def update
  @post = Post.find params[:id]
  authorize @post
  # Rest of your code
end
```

Comment: pundit is a nice suggestion in general, but here installing a 3rd-party gem for a single check looks like overkill

Comment: Sure but had to point out that the user can bypass a button check and a good way to prevent it.

Comment: Just to be fair - I use Pundit all the time and it's a great tool :)